# Cannot boot Windows after Linux partition (winload.efi error)

Tags: partition, windows, uefi

So I have just a single 256 SSD for a notebook that initially had only Windows

I did the following:

1. Booted into Linx Mint Live USB
2. Resized main partition holding Windows OS from 180GB>27GB
3. Created new partition ext4
4. Installed Linux on new partition "alongside Windows" option

Linux works fine, and grub boot loader shows "Windows boot manager" option on startup.

However, selecting this, I receive the following BSOD

> The application or operating system couldn't be loaded because a
> required file is missing or contains errors.
>
> File: WINDOWS system32 winload.efi

I looked around and did the following without avail:

1. Disable Secure Boot
2. Enable Legacy Boot
3. Update grub via `sudo update-grub`

Disk partition in GParted looks as follows, windows OS is on dev/...p4.

Any help would be much appreciated

[image]

Comment: did you compact windows partition before resizing ? maybe windows use less than 27 GB, but file might have been spread on all original partition, not only the "lower" 27 Gb.

Comment: No luck? Surely someone has got this issue before and solved it